# Simplifying nested SQL selects

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL query that I'll call `inner_sql_stmt` that looks something like this:

```
SELECT A, B, C, SUM(a), COUNT(b), SUM(CASE ...), ...
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON ...
GROUP BY A, B, C
```

And this works, but I need to coalesce on the A's (because they represent the same type of object, and here, for reasons that make sense in the problem domain, everything gets summed, so I have a query that I'll call `outer_sql_stmt` that looks like this:

```
SELECT B, C,
       sum(CASE WHEN a > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       sum(...), ...
FROM (
    inner_sql_stmt
) T
GROUP BY B, C
ORDER BY something DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Now it turns out that we also want to add a column called subject, and that's available in another table with lookup using B and C.  It seems logical to do that join only after we've finished the above and done the limit, since without the limit the table size is several orders of magnitude larger.  So this gives

```
SELECT subject, B, C,
       <and name all those other columns>
FROM (
    outer_sql_stmt
) TT
INNER JOIN subject_table ST
  ON TT.B = ST.B AND TT.C = ST.C
ORDER BY something DESC
```

And this strikes me as the Rube Goldberg version of a SQL query, overly complex for what it does.  But I don't see what my alternatives are.

Any suggestions on how to think through refactoring this, or soothing but informed words on why I shouldn't worry about refactoring it?

Comment: Instead of a CASE, you can use FILTER (): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Comment: `... want to add a column called subject, and that's available in another table with lookup using B and C.` Just JOIN the third table ON {B , C}, and add MAX(subject) to the SELECT list

Answer (score 0):

You could join the subject_table inside the `outer_sql_stmt`.

But only if it's a many-to-one relationship.
Or it would change the summed totals.

```
SELECT ST.subject, T.B, T.C,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(...), ...
FROM (
    inner_sql_stmt
) T
LEFT JOIN subject_table ST
  ON ST.B = T.B AND ST.C = T.C
GROUP BY T.B, T.C, ST.subject
ORDER BY something DESC
LIMIT 30
```